# How to initialize multiple variables in C++ to the same value?

Tags: c++, c++11

Would this kind of variable assignment work?

```
double a = 2.0,
x, y, z = 0.5;
```

Would the second line of code work properly and initialize `x, y, z` each to 0.5?

Comment: `x = y =  z = 0.50;`

Comment: Never saw so many upvotes and downvotes happening at the same time so fast on a question/answers set. Gotta be sure of what you answer before doing so or you'll get caught in a downvote spree

Comment: What happens if set equal to the outcome of a function? F ex a random number generator, say something like:

    for (int n = 0; n < sizeofvectortotraverse; n++)
       
    {
         
     int f[size];
     arr[n] = f[size] = distr(eng);
      }

Here, eng is a seeded generator. Will it provide a random number for both arr and f? Or run only once to give arr a rnd number and then f will be given that same value?

Answer (score 19):

No, only `z` would be initialized .You have to write it like this:

```
double x = 0.50, y = x, z = x;
```

But you can write an assignment like this:

```
 double x, y, z;
 x = y = z = 0.50;
```

Comment: Try thinking in terms of `const double`.

Answer (score 19):

Your code leaves `x` and `y` uninitialized. However, a slight rearrangement can save you from repeating an initial value:

```
double a = 2.0, x = 0.50, y = x, z = x;
```

Variables that are declared earlier in a declaration are in scope of later declarations.

This is sometimes particularly useful when evaluating one initializer may have a non-trivial runtime cost. For example, in the following nested loop where `m` is a multimap:

```
for (auto it = m.begin(), kt = it, e = m.end(); it != e; it = kt)
{   //    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

    // handle partition

    for (; kt != e && kt->first == it->first; ++kt)
    {
        // ... handle equal-range
    }
}
```

Comment: The order of initialization is not guaranteed: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53699186/2288628

Answer (score 5):

Simply No. Only *z* will be initialized.

If you try to print them afterwards

`std::cout << a << " " << x << " " << y << " " << z;`

you will get this kind of warning from the compiler:

**warning: 'x' is used uninitialized in this function**

For the sake of clarity I would use the second option that Rabbid76 suggested:

```
 double x, y, z;
 x = y = z = 0.50;
```

Answer (score 4):

The  second line of code:

```
double x;
x = 50.1;
```

actually has a return value.  Usually, it is not caught, or used, but it is there.  So `x = 50.1` returns the value 50.1.

This implies that you could do:

```
double x,y,z;
x = y = z = 50.1;
```

And the value will make its way up the chain where `x = y` returns and the value isn't caught again.  After that line is executed, x, y and z will all have the value 50.1.

Comment: It's not a "return value", because there's no function call. Rather, it is the assignment expression that has a value.

Comment: Last time I checked the assignment operator behaved like a function call. A simplified copy constructor. But hey, if you understood my solution then why feel the need to further confuse the matter?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to **assign** to all three variables, write

```
x = y = z = 0.5;
```

which is equivalent to

```
x = (y = (z = 0.5));
```

The code that you present only **assigns** to `z`.

Comment: I didn't downvote but I think it's because of the confusion between assignment and initialization

Comment: @stackptr: The OP's code doesn't assign anything. It *initializes*. The `=` symbol can mean many different things.

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve what you want doing this:
x = y = z = 0.50;

Answer (score 0):

You could do that in a single line like this:

```
double x = 0.5, y = 0.5, z = 0.5;
```