# Why does x have an unexpected value after trying to initialize it with x, y = a, b?

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    int x, y;
    x, y = 10, 20;
    std::cout << x;
    return 0;
}
```

I expect 10 as output but 16 is coming.
What's the reason? Can someone explain that behavior in c++ please?

Comment: `x,y=10,20;` doesn't do what you think it does! Who taught you to do initialization in that way?? You're probably better served reading a [good book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list), rather than asking about basics here.

Comment: [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: This is very related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35877190 but there's an exact dupe of your question as well. I'll see if I can track it down.

Comment: @Filburt In all fairness, the debugger will just step over this line, and show the new variable values, without explaining what's going on. You either know this language feature or your don't.

Comment: You want either `int x, y; std::tie(x, y) = std::forward_as_tuple(10, 20);`, or `auto [x, y] = std::forward_as_tuple(10, 20);`.

Comment: (that is the second example, the one with `auto [...]`)

Comment: Let's reopen this since there are some interesting ways from C++17 onwards of achieving this.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Using a debugger and inspecting the runtime value will take you one step ahead in that you discover the value of `x` and how it is different from what you'd expect. This is about learning to use a debugger as early as possible instead of just looking at output or a runtime error.

Comment: @kNIG132103 1st and only rule: Don't call me "sir"!

Comment: @kNIG132103 Basically your code invokes _undefined behavior_, because you're accessing an uninitialized variable for output. Undefined behavior is undefined, and generally cannot be reproduced, thus I am voting your question to be closed for that reason now.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`x, y = 10, 20;` is interpreted as `(x), (y = 10), (20);`.

The three expressions are just executed sequentally. `x` and `20` do nothing, and `y = 10` does what it says on the tin.

`x` remains uninitialzied, and reading it is undefined behavior.

---

There is a way to do what you want, but it's a part of the standard library (`#include <tuple>`), not built into the language.

It's also quite verbose, so it might be a better idea to just assign to each variable separately.

If you want to assign to existing variables:

```
int x, y;
std::tie(x, y) = std::forward_as_tuple(10, 20);
```

Or, if you want to create new variables:

```
auto [x, y] = std::forward_as_tuple(10, 20);
```

(the `auto [...]` syntax is called a [structured binding](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/structured_binding), and is available since C++17)

---

If the rhs are variables (lvalues), you can use less verbose `std::tie` instead of `std::forward_as_tuple`.

In some cases you need `std::tuple` instead of `std::forward_as_tuple`, it will copy/move the rhs before assigning them. This is required e.g. when returning the tuple from a function, or if you want to do `std::tie(x, y) = std::tuple(y, x);`.

You can also use `std::tuple` instead of `std::forward_as_tuple` for brevity, is the rhs is inexpensive to copy/move.

Comment: Nice answer !!!

Comment: Is there any advantage of these solutions over just using `x = 10; y = 20;`?

Comment: @mkrieger1 Not really. Edit : At least the last example uses type deduction, `auto x = 10; auto y = 20;` will do that too.

Comment: @mkrieger1 Probably not. Except when you want to do something like `std::tie(x, y, z) = std::tuple(y, z, x);` (and hate the idea of having an extra variable :P), or return a bunch of variables from a function.

Answer (score 6):

It seems that you want to do in C++ what is ok in languages like Python. This line

```
x, y = 10, 20
```

in Python will do what you want: it will initialize x to 10 and y to 20. But in C++ it does something very different. The comma operator in C++ works as follows: given `E1, E2, E3;` expression C++ will evaluate `E1` and discard its result, evaluate `E2` and discard its result, evalute `E3` and return it as a value of the entire expression (in your case it will be discarded as well, since there is no left side).

And so in C++ the

```
x, y = 10, 20
```

expression does what follows: reads `x`, sets `y = 10` and reads `20`. Therefore your

```
std::cout << x;
```

line has Undefined Behaviour, you print an uninitialized variable (well, you already have UB in the expression itself as well). This means that anything can happen: `x` can be anything, including 16 in your case, but also your program may simply crash.

Note that C++ does have tools to emulate this "Python like behaviour" (see HolyBlackCat's answer) but I suggest simply doing

```
int x = 10;
int y = 20;
```

Not a one-liner, but easy to read and understand.

Comment: I don't know Python, but will that line really initialize `x` to 10 and `y` to 20 when it has `y = 10`?

Comment: @yano Yes, in Python it will do that. In Python `x, y = 10, 20` is equivalent to `x = 10` and `y = 20`.

Comment: *Not a one-liner* Ehm, this is one line: `int x=10, y=20;`

Comment: @MatG sure. However I'd rather initialize each variable in a separate line. Looks cleaner to me. Well, it is a matter of style and opinion.

Comment: @freakish You got me, in my code I actually use your style

Comment: @MatG: As I'm sure you know, the comma style can bite you when declaring pointer types.